# windows 8 network profiles

Tags: networking, windows-8

Does anyone know of a way to have multiple network profiles in windows 8.

I need to define at least two network (cabled) configs, for two distinct network I need to connect to. But I want to do this without having to go to the adapter properties every time I change networks.

Thanks in advance for any sugestion.

Comment: Sounds like a job for a router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Tool [NetSetMan](http://www.netsetman.com/?lang=en). This tool allows you to configure different profiles and switch between them very easily.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I dont know why you would want to do this, this is one of the problems DHCP solves.

If only one of your networks have DHCP you can use the APIPA settings to set up your config for the other network, then leave your network settings to automatic. This way when it tries to pick up a DHCP server, and cant find one, it will use your custom configuration.

[image]

Alternatively you could write a batch script that uses netsh to change your network info, or the way i would do it if i really had to would be through PowerShell, [which i have an article on over at How-To Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/112660/how-to-change-your-ip-address-using-powershell/).

Comment: thanks for your anwser, but I tried using alternate configs, but since from one location I have to get to the other (through the gateway) it does not work. A script is a option, but I'm trying to see if its a last resort